# How to create a BulkSendApllication for Multiple destinations?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I tried to create a BulkSend Application that sends data to multiple sink nodes, but the following snippet

```
 BulkSendHelper source ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",
                     InetSocketAddress (clientInterfaces.GetAddress (1), port));
```

is able to send for only single sink node. How to make it work for multiple sinks??

Thanks in advance,, :D

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to set the `BulkSenkApplication` to send to multiple sink nodes was to simply workaround it by creating multiple `BulkSendApplication`(s) where each instance sends to a different sink node. I think that is the intended way. The App is suppose to be very simple.